# Can't identify the cuda device

Tags: tensorflow, nvidia, tensorflow2.0, tensorrt

Python 3.6.9

Tensorflow 2.1.0 gpu supported

Cuda 10.0

TensorRT 6.0

GPU - 1

Used to convert a Tensorflow savedmodel to TensorRT ( `https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/tf-trt-user-guide/index.html`)

I get the error even after `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0` or `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1`

**Error log :**

> Can't identify the cuda device. Running on device 0 Segmentation fault
>   (core dumped)

Comment: What code did you use? The one provided in the documentation?

Comment: Yes............